# How to insert variable into file at a specified position

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm building a script that will search for all the files in a certain directory.
Then I put the files that it found in the file files.txt, like below:

```
ls /opt/files/ | while read line
do
        files=`echo $line | grep -o '[^ ]*$'`
        echo $files >> files.txt
done
```

Now I want to put the found file in an other file called config.properties at a specified position.
Below you will see how the config.properties file looks like.

```
rest.server.url=https\://hostname/RestService/
rest.username=user
rest.password=pass
rest.response.type=json
hotfix.async=false
hotfix.operation=hotfix
hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/<file>
```

So at the  I want to insert the filename that has been found.
I came up with the following code below:

```
cat files.txt | while read files
do
        #How can I code the part below?
        insert $files into config.properties at line hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/<file>
done
```

Only how can I insert $files in the config.properties file at the position of  ?
I have a feeling it can be done with awk or sed, but not sure.

Comment: The line `files=$(echo $line | grep -o '[^ ]*$')` is very unusual.  Since you aren't double quoting the argument to echo, any white space in `$line` will be munged.  But the purpose of the grep seems to be to strip all text before the final space.  Did you mean to do `grep -o '[^/]*%'` to try to get the basename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try and integrate this solution using sed:

```
sed -i -E "s/(^hotfix\.dlFilePath\=\/opt\/files\/)(.*$)?/\1$files/" config.properties
```

Please note the use of double quotes around the substitution expression in sed to make the shell expand variables. So, with a variable like this

```
files="foo"
```

and given this input (assuming that the <file> was just a placeholder):

```
rest.server.url=https\://hostname/RestService/
rest.username=user
rest.password=pass
rest.response.type=json
hotfix.async=false
hotfix.operation=hotfix
hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/
```

you'll get this result

```
rest.server.url=https\://hostname/RestService/
rest.username=user
rest.password=pass
rest.response.type=json
hotfix.async=false
hotfix.operation=hotfix
hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/foo
```

Comment: I have tried this, after the sed command I do see that it placed the filename after `hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/`
But when I do a cat config.properties after the sed command, the filename is gone.

Comment: You can add `-i` (in-place editing) option to sed like this `sed -i -E ...` if you want to edit the file.

Comment: If I do a `sed -i -E` the first time it is good it get `hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/foo`, but the secondtime I run it I get `hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/barfoo` so I will not replace the foo with the new file `bar` but it will be placed in front it.

Maybe an other idea is to think the line `hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/foo
` is not there. So first add the line with sed -i -E. And when the execution is done where I need the config.properties file for. And the delete the line `hotfix.dlFilePath=/opt/files/foo`

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer -- I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to generate the file `config.properties` so that it has one stanza for each file that you find?  Just do:

```
for file in /opt/files/*; do 
cat << EOF
rest.server.url=https\://hostname/RestService/
rest.username=user
rest.password=pass
rest.response.type=json
hotfix.async=false
hotfix.operation=hotfix
hotfix.dlFilePath=$file
EOF
done > config.properties
```